# Problems to get the correct Connection Pool in Glassfish 4

Tags: jsp, glassfish

I am using Glassfish 4.0. I have set a connection pool to MySql. Every thing looks fine to get the correct pool with:

```
Context ctx =new InitialContext();
DataSource ds = ctx.lookup("jdbc/music");
```

but when I try to use it in a jsp page:

```
<sql:query var="result" dataSource="jdbc/music">
```

What I get is a connection to Derby Pool.

Any help?

Comment: Is it works like: @Resource(name="jdbc/music") DataSource ds;

Comment: It does not work using  annotation to inject the resource referred to by it. It does not resolve the proper jndi name, and instead it uses jbdc/_default which refers to Derby pool

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is a bug in GlassFish 4 or some kind of misconfiguration but to use a datasource in this way you have to define a resource reference either in your `web.xml` or in a `context.xml`.

The `web.xml` entry should look similar to this:

```
<resource-ref>
  <res-ref-name>jdbc/music</res-ref-name>
  <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
  <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

Make sure you haven set up the correct `res-type` for your configured datasource. If you already have something like this (I suppose because if I remove this entry I get a different error) or if this doesn't fix the problem you may have to set up the resource reference in `glassfish-web.xml` too. 
It should look similar to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE glassfish-web-app PUBLIC "-//GlassFish.org//DTD GlassFish Application Server 3.1 Servlet 3.0//EN" "http://glassfish.org/dtds/glassfish-web-app_3_0-1.dtd">
<glassfish-web-app error-url="">
  <class-loader delegate="true"/>
  <resource-ref>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/music</res-ref-name>
    <jndi-name>jdbc/music</jndi-name>
  </resource-ref>
</glassfish-web-app>
```

**See also:**

- [Glassfish - No suitable driver for mysql when trying to connect with datasource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17378840/glassfish-no-suitable-driver-for-mysql-when-trying-to-connect-with-datasource)
- [glassfish 4 & MySQL & JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17427640/glassfish-4-mysql-jstl)

Comment: Thanks for your comment @unwichtich. Of course that I have the resource configured in web.xml. I already found the problem. The folowing line was missing in the resource-ref section in web.xml
  <mapped-name>jdbc/music</mapped-name>. It was not necessary in previous versions of Glassfish. I am just trying to find why is this necessary now.